# Git CI - How to check that a specific file changed on a new version?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set a simple Git CI.

But instead of rebuilding everytime, I want to be able to check if a specific file (let's say `requirements.txt`) suffered any changes between the last version/commit and the current.

Is there a git command for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command has a signature to limit the path, so you could do this:

```
git diff HEAD HEAD~1 --no-patch --exit-code requirements.txt
```

The return code will be 1 if the file changed in the latest commit, or 0 if not. You can then access the return code like this (in bash):

```
echo $?
```

Discussion

- The two  arguments HEAD and HEAD~1 are the tip of the current branch (your latest commit) and the commit just behind it.
- The --no-patch option suppresses the actual diff output.
- The --exit-code argument causes the return code to be 1 when there are differences or 0 otherwise.

Comment: I'm assuming I need to clone the whole repository for this? For example in a remote CI service

Comment: The CI tools I'm familiar with always clone the repository. I would expect the CI service to check out the branch being built, in which case you shouldn't need to do anything. They usually expose predefined environment variables with information such as the name of the branch being built. For Gitlab it's CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME, for Jenkins it's GIT_BRANCH. You can specify the branch name instead of HEAD in the git diff command, like "git diff $GIT_BRANCH $GIT_BRANCH~1..." if it's not already checked out.

Comment: Does GitHub Actions CI have something similar?